# Moderator deleted my answers and I don't understand why

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderators

I wrote a module for an open-source library to fulfill a need I had. I Google'd to see if anyone else was having the same issue so I could tell them about it. I saw two questions on StackOverflow with the accepted answer of "the library can't do that out of the box". I added an answer pointing future Googlers to the module I wrote.

Answers:

[Jackson 2 support for versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38805094/1073826)

[Upgrade path for json file format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38805129/1073826)

I have reviewed [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and the only bullet that I could see possibly applying is "barely more than a link to an external site". The GitHub link has extensive code example on how to use the module.

If I was searching for a solution and I came across a link to an open-source solution that would solve my need, I would be upvoting not flagging.

1. I understand moderators work very hard and have to sift through a lot of crap, but can someone explain the thought process here?
2. If I edit the answer to include a code snippet, can it be undeleted?
3. Should there be a feature added to let moderators write in why they deleted a post (instead of just the canned link to a FAQ page)?

Comment: _"If I edit the answer to include a code snippet, can it be undeleted?"_ - try it, flag it and see.

Comment: Fair enough.  I do wish I understood why this is getting downvoted.  It's really frustrating to take the time to write up something up and then just have it anonymously downvoted without any explanation.

Comment: [Meta voting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) doesn't always make sense, don't worry about it. As for #3, the feature already exists: moderators can post a comment explaining the deletion (even after the deletion), if they feel there's something to explain.

Comment: @JonPeterson There is no real need to explain votes in comments on meta, the answers generally give pretty solid hints as to what's up. You might wonder why to vote at all on a support question: yeah well the button is there you know, it can be pressed ;) Don't take it too seriously, even downvoted content has great value - apparently people do not agree / do not want / find flaws in the premise of the content. Downvotes simply make that very visible, on meta without any repercussions to the author of the content. Don't let it stop you from posting meta questions or answers.

Comment: I appreciate the responses Yannis and Gimby.  Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue I see with the answers it that to the outside observer, it doesn't look like you're addressing the problem they face using words they're using.

So to someone who may not know as much as you do about it; it looks like you're giving a generic blanket answer (and then copy/pasting it) to multiple questions.

That's a no-no.

Also, touting your own library without showing how it specifically solves the specific problem the user has also makes it seem like spam.

'General' examples aren't helpful in a Q&A, since people come to a question when they have the same specific problem.

Your answer where the user asks for an 'upgrade' path could use some tie in between the words they use ('upgrade path') and your word 'versioning'.  How does one relate to the other? If you were going to teach the right terminology, how would you do that? would you just disregard the terminology the asker used? (I hope not)

Also, your answer should be tailored to answer the specific question asked.  If you find yourself saying "Here's a generic example of how to use my library", you're going to find yourself in trouble.

1. No one wants generic examples, they want examples that solve their specific issue.
2. People who vote and flag see someone saying "Here's my library and here's a generic example of how to use it" are going to flag that post as spam. It's a thinly concealed advertisement that doesn't actually help the OP.
3. Moderators get flagged when two answers have similar content;  it's a sign of spamming.  You don't want to be caught up in that; and the best way to not get caught up in that is also the best way to answer any question:

Be specific. Be helpful. Answer the question asked in the way it was asked.

Your answers give generic examples using Groovy (something neither OP asked for) and one of the questions asked if it supported specific operations, something your answer didn't even broach.

Comment: I whole-heartedly disagree with your opinion of the question regarding "does Jackson support this same feature that GSON has?". The module I am referencing handles the same functionality (more in fact) that the OP is asking about.  As for the other question, I'll concede that it could probably be tailored a little better to the wording of the question.  Can you please reconsider undeleting 38805094 and allowing me to rewrite 38805129.  I truly believe this module can be very valuable to people looking to version their JSON with the most popular JVM-based JSON framework.

Comment: I've given you actionable information on how to get your answers undeleted. Follow the advice laid in my answer and flag your answers, and they'll be undeleted.  You can rewrite both without them being undeleted first.

Comment: I didn't realize I could re-write them without getting in trouble for posting on the same question my original answer was deleted from.  Done.

Comment: @JonPeterson You "Rewrite" them by clicking "edit" on your answer, not posting a new answer to the same question.

Comment: Sorry, I had already edited them once and flagged.  I couldn't tell if they were still in review or had been rejected.  I misunderstood "you can rewrite both without them being undeleted first".

Answer (score 11):

Your answers to the two questions are identical aren't they?

Moderators do get notified about users supplying the same answer to lots of questions. That may well be a contributing factor to why they were deleted.

- If you think the questions are duplicates you should flag or vote to close them as duplicates
- If you think they are not duplicates you should provide answers tailored to each question

Comment: Yes, the first revisons that Martijn deleted are identical and just links to the project and *go see this* as supporting text.

Comment: I can understand this in most cases, but the two questions are: "Does anyone know if Jackson2 supports versioning [...] ?" and "What have other people done to handle upgrading file formats?"  I feel like a duplicate answer of "Here is a module that will do it for you" is applicable to both.  Regardless, I have edited the answers to include examples of how to use the module and flagged them for review.