# How can I ask a moderator why they deleted my answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, private-messaging

Apparently moderators can delete answers without specifying the reason. However we are notified of who did it. Can we write a direct message to them?

Comment: The answer below might not be a good answer to the question, but this question, should it not be a duplicate, sounds like a very reasonable question.

Answer (score -18):

If your answer was deleted by a moderator and you would like to contact them to ask them for the reason, you should create a post in the appropriate meta. Link the user and the deleted post.

Examples:

- [Why was my answer deleted by a moderator?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380575/why-was-my-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator)
- [Moderator deleted my answers and I don't understand why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332921/moderator-deleted-my-answers-and-i-dont-understand-why)
- [Why was my answer deleted by a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152883/why-was-my-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator)
- [What should I do when a moderator deletes my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70938/what-should-i-do-when-a-moderator-deletes-my-post)

Beware to post on the per-site meta that corresponds to the deleted answer, meta.stackexchange and meta.stackoverflow are different sites.

Comment: Note that moderators are not obligated to respond to such posts.  Users whose posts are deleted by a moderator should consult [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) first.

Comment: As to the post you cited, the reasons for deletion should already be self-evident, especially since Vim actually has proper ways to exit.  You may not like or agree with those ways, but Stack Overflow isn't a soapbox.

Comment: Why the answer was deleted was not the question, I asked how I can ask the moderator. 
-
Yeah, I read the link you posted, the only relevant part link might be: "If your post was deleted by a moderator, you can flag that post, writing a note in the "in need of moderator intervention" section explaining the situation and requesting undeletion, or make a request on the per-site meta."

So, yeah, making a request on the per-site meta, this agrees with my answer. Providing a useful artifact such as this question is much better than redirecting users to read that wall of text.

Comment: Also, let's note the amount of bureocracy one needs to go through in order to simply contact a moderator who deleted one's answer. This contrasts starkly against the standards set by locked questions, where the specific reasons are provided and well documented. I'm uncertain what causes this assymetry.

Comment: You should not raise a moderator flag to ask a question. We don't answer questions asked in moderator flags, and we will simply decline the flag. You *can* ask on Meta, but we'd recommend not doing so when the answer is obvious. Robert directed you to a long-form FAQ, but [this is the better link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). The Help Center already contains an explanation of why some answers are deleted, and *this is linked from deleted answers*.